# Return data to client in ruby handler and keep evaluating code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, mongoid, ruby-grape

I'm coming from a nodejs background with mongoose so forgive me.

I don't want my handlers in my sinatra app to have to wait for mongoid models to save before sending back a response, right now I have things like:

```
get '/test' do
  user = User.find(..)
  user.prop = 'change'
  user.save
  { success: 1, user_id: user.id }
end
```

however I don't want my client to wait for the save to succeed before returning data (for some cases in my app I want to be thorough and make sure saves work before returning success to the user but for other handlers it is unimportant).

A better sequence of events would be:

```
get '/test' do
  user = User.find(..)
  user.prop = 'change'
  return to client: { success: 1, user_id: user.id }
  user.save
end
```

In Express with node (and mongoose) this is simply:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  User.where(...).findOne(function(err, user) {
    user.prop = 'change';
    res({ success: 1, user_id: user._id });
    user.save();
  });
});
```

which is fantastic because I simply return my response to the user and continue on.

I guess I could use delayed_job for this and send my changes to a background job to "save" but this seems like a terrible design and is ultimately writing to mongo anyway so it defeats the purpose.

Is there some way from my sinatra/grape/rails/any handler to return data to the client and then keep running code?

Comment: rails servers don't tend to work that way. They return stuff to the user after everything is done. You can't just keep processing while returning something to the user - that would require two threads (one to keep processing the save, and one to return stuff to the user and end), and you don't have that in rails unless you hand code it.

Comment: Since mongodb says it wrote successfuly even if it doesnt know yet, you shouldn't waste much time